# Proposition I.7.1 of Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I wonder why "the irreducible components of $Y\cap Z$ correspond to the minimal prime ideals $p$ of the principal ideal $(f)$ in $A(Y)$"?

Comment: Let $A(Y) = k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]/I(Y)$ and $Z = V((f))$ then $Y \cap Z = V( (f,I(Y)) = V(f A(Y))$. The irreducible components of $V(J)$ are the $V(P_j)$ where the $P_j$ are the minimal prime ideals containing $J$.

Comment: @reuns what's $J$?

Comment: Use the inclusion-reversing correspondence between prime ideals and subvarieties. Irreducible variety is equivalent to prime ideal cutting out that variety, so maximal proper irreducible subvarieties correspond to what under this correspondence?